# How to wrap from the other end with textwrap?

Tags: python, string, list

`wrap` in `textwrap` wraps from left to right:

```
from textwrap import wrap
print(wrap('1100010101', 4))
```

returns: `['1100', '0101', '01']`

Is there a way to wrap it from right to left, so it returns: `['11', '0001', '0101']`?

Comment: If you actually need to represent binary data by 4, maybe it will be easier just to add two zeroes in the beginning? `s = "0" * (4 - len(s) % 4) + s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first reverse `'1100010101'` then reverse each element and at end reverse result of `wrap` like below:

```
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> st = '1100010101'[::-1]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[::-1] , wrap(st, 4)))[::-1]
['11', '0001', '0101']
```